# Laravel 5.3 relationship

Tags: php, laravel

Here is my code:

```
class Company extends Model {
    public function employees() {
        return $this->hasMany('Employee');   
    }
}

class Employee extends Model{
    protected $table = "user_role_company";
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
    public function company(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Company');
     }
}

class User extends Authenticatable {
    public function employee(){
        return $this->hasMany('Employee');
    }
}
```

If I run:

```
$recordsTotal = User::with(['employee' => function ($query) use ($company_id) {
    $query->where('company_id', $company_id);
}])->count();
```

It returns all the users count not only the empolyee count.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, do you have a 'company_id' and a 'user_id' column in the Employee model/DB?

Anyways, you can try this query instead.

```
$recordsTotal = User::whereHas('employee', function ($q) use ($company_id) {
     $q->where('company_id', $company_id);
})->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating relationships you need to reference the entire namespace or the class like User::Class

Comment: namespace is referenced

Answer (score 0):

When using relationships you can declare the Modal::class on the relationship given that the primary key and local key of both tables reference the correct values so for example you could have:

```
class Company extends Model {
    public function employees() {
        return $this->hasMany(Employee::class, 'company_id');   
    }
}
```

This will reference the company_id column on the Employee table or what ever table you have set within the Employee Modal.

You can also pass the foreign_key, local_key to the relation like so:

```
class Company extends Model {
   public function employees() {
    return $this->hasMany(Employee::class, 'foreign_key', 'local_key');   
   }
}
```

A similar example would be:

```
class Company extends Model {
   public function employees() {
    return $this->hasMany(Employee::class, 'company_id', 'company_id');   
   }
}
```

Depending on your database structure you should be able to just pass the modal::class to the relation however it is difficult to give a perfect working example without knowing your exact database structure and how you have your keys / identifiers setup, Meaning for example is your primary key named id or company_id. Depending on that structure you can give this a shot.

```
class Company extends Model {
public function employees() {
    return $this->hasMany(Employee::class);   
}
```

}

Also remember when returning a collection to either loop over the array or simply use $company->employees()->get() another option would be to use ->first() instead of get() to use the first record in the array.

Hope this helps, I am no means an expert and still learning laravel my self, if you have any further issues with this relation or cant get the code to work i will try help where i can.

Also worth taking a look here:  **[Laravel Docs (Eloquent: Relationships)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships)**